# Web development: how to show all errors (make errors verbose)?

Tags: javascript, html, django

For example in Django:

```
S = request.POST.get("NonexistentField") # There is no error, it fails silently
```

How to show all errors in html, javascript, django?

Comment: make sure that `debug = True` in your settings file.  A good python tutorial would be indispensable.

Answer (score 5):

Why should there be an error there? In Python, `dict.get('key')` is specifically designed not to raise an exception if the key doesn't exist. If you *want* to cause an exception, do `dict['key']` directly.

Answer (score 0):

try [firebug](http://getfirebug.com) for firefox, it can help debugging

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the errors just for development purposes, you might want to take a look at Django debug toolbar. It is a great tool that show you data about http headers, sql queries,etc.

https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar